# How does Account Abstraction Paymaster compare the value of ERC20 and Ether?

Tags: erc-20, account-abstraction, paymaster

To the best of my knowledge, the off-chain value is utilized by Chainlink and the on-chain value is utilized by uniswap's oracle.

However, I don't see anything related to Chainlink or Uniswap in the code in the Account Abstraction that actually bills the gas bill with ERC20.
(I did see biconomy code.)

How does Account Abstraction Paymaster compare the value of ERC20 and gas?
I would be very grateful if you could share link me to some code for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently on testnet the biconomy uses `VerifyingPaymaster` which just signs the userOps in order to execute it.

In order to use other paymaster such as `TokenPaymaster`, `LegacyTokenPaymaster`. You can refer to this github link provided by `eth-infintism` [here](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/tree/develop/contracts/samples). In `TokenPaymaster` contract it asks for a uniswap router in its constructor.

I hope this helps